# Python Parameterize Formatting

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

So I was wondering if there was a way to parameterize the format operator

For example

```
>>> '{:.4f}'.format(round(1.23456789, 4))
'1.2346
```

However, is there anyway to do something like this instead

```
>>> x = 4
>>> '{:.xf}'.format(round(1.23456789, x))
'1.2346
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a little bit of *string concatenation*. Check out the code below:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> string = '{:.' + str(x) + 'f}'       # concatenate the string value of x
>>> string                               # you can see that string is the same as '{:.4f}'
'{:.4f}'
>>> string.format(round(1.23456789, x))  # the final result
'1.2346'
>>>
```

or if you wish to do this without the extra `string` variable:

```
>>> ('{:.' + str(x) + 'f}').format(round(1.23456789, x)) # wrap the concatenated string in parenthesis
'1.2346'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes this does answer the question. It's such a simple answer, yet I hadn't considered it. Thank you!

Comment: @T.Smith You may consider accepting the answer then.