# why can't you pass a variable into format specifier python

Tags: python-3.x, format

I wonder why you can't do this?

```
s = "Here is a string"
x = 20
print(f"{s:^x}")
```

Comment: I answered this exact question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893323/12442137) lol!
A hint: Use string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
>>> print(f"{s:^{x}}")
 Here is a string 

>>> len(f"{s:^{x}}")
20
```

Comment: Bracket-ception. You're welcome. Please accept the answer if that's ok for you!